# Echo a XHTML tag

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml

When I try to echo most of XTHML tags inside a PHP loop which one echo's data from a MySQL it just shows text in browser. I'm running XAMPP Control Panel with Apache and MySQL for tests.

CODE:

```
echo "<textarea readonly>";
while ($wiersz = mysql_fetch_array($sql_wynik_zapytania)) 
{
echo "   ".$wiersz['NICK'].":\n";
echo $wiersz['KOMENT']."\n"."<hr />"."\n";
}
echo "</textarea>";
```

The results in browser:

```
   NICK:
a
<hr />
   NICK:
asdaa
<hr />
   pallluch:
cccc
```

"a" "asdaa" "cccc" are just random texts added to table in databse for tests.

Echo  works perfectly fine with `<textarea>`, but `<hr>` doesn't seems to.

Can anyone help?

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) which has been **removed** entirely from the latest version of PHP. You should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Your document isn't XHTML by the way. If it was, the browser would complain loudly about the error in the start tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A textarea element can't contain anything other than plain text.

You are writing invalid HTML and the browser is trying to recover by treating the `<` character as plain text instead of the start of a tag.

It looks like you aren't using the textarea to accept user input anyway (you've made it readonly). Don't use a textarea element here. You probably want to use `<pre>` instead.

Comment: Oh, this works, thanks. I know how to make it scrollable, but how can i format '<pre>'  to show for example 20 letters in line and then go to next one?